# Calculating the value of a series for large n (formula, instead of iteration)

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus

I'm looking for a formula to evaluate the series described below for very large n, as iterating through this algorithm would take way too long. I'm not looking for coding help (this would be the wrong place to ask) but I don't know how to phrase the question, except in terms of pseudo-code:


$result = n(n+1)/2$

$k = 0$

while $n>9$:

... $n=n-9$

... $result=result+(9·10^k·n(n+1)/2)$

... $k=k+1$


With large n, there would be a large number of iterations; hence, I'm looking for a formula to calculate the result directly.

Comment: Are you able to reformat your code as a math expression?

Comment: What thinkingeye commented.  More specifically, if $R(n)$ is the complete result of the iterations when you start with $n$, what are $R(11), R(20),$ and $R(29)$.  Can you manually compute these, then find a pattern, and then algebraically express $R(n)$ as a polynomial in $n$.  Note that you would need to first calculate $c =\lfloor \frac{n}{9}\rfloor$ (i.e. $c$ is the largest positive integer less than or equal to $(n/9).$  Then, your algorithm will have $(c+1)$ iterations unless $n$ is a multiple of 9, in which case it would have only $c$ iterations.